# Three 'First Post' reviews already reviewed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reviewing

Title says it all. I just reviewed *3* items that already had a "Welcome to PPCG" comment. Since 2 different people had reviewed them, I assumed that they hadn't forgot to click, "I'm done". [image]

Comment: It takes more than one review to remove something from a review queue.

Comment: @quartata Really? I never knew that. I have never seen this before.

Comment: @quartata That doesn't seem to be true for the **First Posts** queue.

Comment: Furthermore, how do you know those people did the review? For all you know, those people may have seen the answer while browsing the site, and not through actual review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to *assume* anything. As soon as you get the privilege of reviewing posts in a specific queue, you can switch to the **history** tab to see which actions have been taken by whom. For first posts, the history can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history).

In this history, if you click on the action that has been taken, you're lead to the review task for that specific post. That information is completely public, as long as you have a direct link. For the post from the screenshot, you can find its review [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/31019).

As you can see, only one user (you) has reviewed the post, which completed the review task and thus removed the post from the review queue.

While it is *possible* that there is a bug that doesn't record all reviews, I think it's far more likely that the commenters either forgot to click **I'm done** (still unlikely) or that they simply found the answers while browsing PPCG and didn't use the review system at all.